# Exporting 1:M relate in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, relates, one-to-many

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

I have a relate established between a US Census shapefile and other US federal data (FCC form 477). The 477 data is going to have many records for each census block.

A relate displays properly but isn't queryable. I can't export the data because that only gives me one record instead of many records.

How do I get a new data set that has all records?

Answer (score 1):

Having defined your relate in ArcMap you then select the feature(s) on the map (your US census shapefile).

Imagine you have selected 1 polygon and you know there should be 10 rows in your related table. To get to those 10 rows so you can export them you need to pass the selection through to the related table.

This is easy, you open the attribute table of your census shapefile, this would have 1 polygon selected. You then pass the selection to the related table by clicking on the button shown below.

[image: Relate records]

The attribute table for the related table opens with the 10 selected rows. You then use the standard approach to export your selection.